# 3 column layout in LaTeX (1st only graphics, 2nd and 3rd text)?

Tags: graphics, columns, landscape

How is it possible to organize a document (landscape orientated) in a graphic and two text column?

1st: only graphics (under the headings of the import location)
2nd and 3rd: text

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Take a look on the package `flowfram`.

Comment: Without some more detail this is 'unclear'. For example, what is the structure of you input: do we need to allow for floats or can placement be done manually?